# How to import self-signed SSL certificate to Glassfish 4.1 Webserver

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, keystore

I am trying to download the content of HTTPs URLs using  HttpsURLConnection. This works fine with sites that have a valid SSL certificate from someone like Verisign etc... But, how do I trust a 3rd party/self-signed certificate in my Glassfish / JRE Keystore?